WSL 2 Linux distro is uninstalled when Windows 10 is rebooted
My org has several Windows 10 22H2 19045 VMs running in Azure Virtual Desktop. We're using an image size that supports nested virtualization. We've enabled the WSL, Hyper-V, and VM Platform features and have seen users run Docker Desktop without issue. WSL is upgraded to WSL2 and all kernel updates are installed through Windows Update. We use FSLogix for persistent user profiles.
I am able to install a Linux distro (Ubuntu, in this case) both through the Microsoft Store and using wsl --install -d Ubuntu. When done through the store, a small notice pops up telling me it's done and asks to either launch it or pin it to the start menu. I typically launch it to complete the installation.
Installation proceeds and asks me for a username and password to complete the process. After entering these I'm given my command prompt. When looking in File Explorer, Ubuntu shows up under the Linux header as network folder and I can find it under C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.... It also shows up in my MS Store Library.
BUT...when I shut down my desktop VM and restart it later, it is gone. Not just from the Linux header in File Explorer, but MS Store shows that it isn't installed and it isn't in my AppData folder, either.
I don't expect this is normal behavior. I can't imagine it's designed to be reinstalled every time it's needed. I haven't been able to find any logs either. Anyone ever see/experience this, know what's going on, and/or know how to fix it.
EDIT:
Thinking on what I said about it showing up in File Explorer as a network folder, I recalled seeing on other sites that it would show up as an ext4 volume in Disk Management. I'm not seeing this. This makes me think that what is happening is that WSL is installing it in a manner that Windows sees it as the network folder so when I reboot, that "connection" is lost and Ubuntu is no longer seen as installed.
Is there something I need to configure to force it to persist as an ext4 volume?
EDIT 2:
When looking at the properties for the Ubuntu directory in File Explorer, it shows as \\wsl.localhost. Is this the case regardless of being installed to a volume, VHD, what-have-you?

Have you talked to your system Administrator about what’s happening? It sounds like you are being served a VM based off a snapshot with these features disabled, and when you reboot, you are being served a new VM. This from a user perspective would be seamless, as user profiles can be roaming, which means you wouldn’t necessarily know your being served a new VM.

I am the sys admin :D. We use personal VMs in an AVD host pool. They power off when users log out, but otherwise persist from one session to the next. Users have general admin permissions on their own VMs; they can install applications and modify system settings that aren't controlled by GPO (we don't advertise the system settings, though). WSL is not controlled by GPO.

Are these features the only thing that is being rolled back when you shutdown the VM?

It isn't the features; those persist. Only the Linux distro installation is being rolled back.

"Is this the case regardless of being installed to a volume, VHD, what-have-you?" - Yes

So, are other applications from the Windows Store being uninstalled when the VM is shut down? Windows has no built-in support for EXT4. Where exactly did you read about this EXT4 volume?

I misread it. It is actually a VHD called ext4.vhdx. But I don't see this anywhere.

If you don’t have that virtual Hdd then a wsl2 distribution doesn’t exist on your system
